# Remove duplicates from NSArray of Custom Objects also compare and edit same

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have two `NSMutableArrays`. Each contains a custom word object in it. Custom word has 2 properties text and frequency. Now I want to combine these two `arrays` in such a way that, if these two arrays has same text in it, then it should compare the frequency of those two text and select the highest frequency of the two. And also it should remove the duplicates from the `array`.
I tried every logic for this but was not able to do this. Can any body help me with the logic for this. Following the code. But it should also remove the duplicates.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < [array count]; j++)  {
    if ([[[array objectAtIndex:i]firstWord] isEqualToString:[[array objectAtIndex:j] firstWord]]) {

      if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] frequency] < [[array objectAtIndex:j] frequency]) {
        CustomWordFrequency *word = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        word.frequency = [[array objectAtIndex:j] frequency];
        [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:word];
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what code you tried yet???

Comment: I tried using the two for loops one inside another for same array. But it crashed a lot.

Comment: It would be great if provide some small example with less objects (1 or 2).Like, Array1->this data, Array2->this data. Result array requires -> this data. So it would be a clear view of your question and might help us to think over logical part.

Comment: @Prernachavan: Can you paste the crashed code ?

Comment: why are you checking 
if ([[array objectAtIndex:i]firstWord] <[[array objectAtIndex:j] firstWord])
as this is never going to be true because before that only you are checking
if ([[[array objectAtIndex:i]firstWord] isEqualToString:[[array objectAtIndex:j] firstWord]])
this means if it comes inside first if condition then it is equal so no use checking same things with "<" sign

Comment: Your code snippet is looping through the same array twice. Is this what you really want to do?

Comment: I think in the second if condition you should check frequency.

Comment: @jsumners Not twice, but n^2 times. The code above is going to, at best, create duplicates int the array you're iterating.

Comment: So, the requirement is: merge the arrays, sort by the frequency and remove the duplicates? There must be a secondary sort or random for the items with the same frequency?

Answer (score 0):

1. Combine the two arrays.
2. Sort the resulting array by text ASC, frequency DESC
3. Loop through the array
   a. Look at the next item in the array.  If the text is the same as the current word, remove it from the array.  If it's different, continue looping.

   ```
   NSArray *combined = [firstArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:secondArray];
   [combined sortUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
     NSComparisonResult *result = [firstObject.text compare:secondObject.text];
     if (result == NSOrderedAscending) return NSOrderedAscending;
     if (result == NSOrderedDescending) return NSOrderedDescending;
     if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
       result = [firstObject.frequency compare:secondObject.frequency];
       if (result == NSOrderedAscending) return NSOrderedDescending;
       if (result == NSOrderedDescending) return NSOrderedAscending;
       if (result == NSOrderedSame) return NSOrderedSame;
     }
   }];
   for (int i = 0; i < [combined count] - 2; ++i) {
      CustomWordFrequency *word = [combined objectAtIndex:i];
      int j = i + 1;
      while ([word.text compare:[combined objectAtIndex:j].text == NSOrderedSame) {
        [combined removeObjectAtIndex:j];
        j++;
        if (j == [combined count]) {break;}
      }
      if (i >= [combined count] - 2) {break;} // the count keeps changing so check here
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *combinedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
BOOL flagForMatchFound = FALSE;
for(CustomWordFrequency *firstWord in firstArray)
 {
   flagForMatchFound = FALSE;
   for(CustomWordFrequency *secondWord in secondArray)
   {
       if([firstWord.firstWord isEqualToString:secondWord.firstWord])
       {
          if(firstWord.frequency >= secondWord.frequency)
          {
               [combinedArray addObject:firstWord];
               flagForMatchFound = TRUE;
          }
          else
               [combinedArray addObject:secondWord];
       }
       else
       {
          if(!flagForMatchFound)
              [combinedArray addObject:secondWord]; 
       }
   }
 }
```